# Touchpad doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04 in Thinkpad L14

Tags: 22.04, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

A while ago I disabled the touchpad.

But now I need to get it working again and there is no way to get it back on.

The x-input:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3       id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera: USB Camera                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to do that:

```
xinput set-prop 4 "Device Enabled" 1
```

but not works...

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The question is unclear. `sudo modprobe psmouse` doesn't disable touchpad. Other commands are also unclear. Why would you think they should enable touchpad? Please [edit] the question and add output of `xinput` command.

Comment: sorry @Pilot6 , you are right!

Comment: Your touchpad is not detected. You need to find out if it is a PS/2 touchpad or something else.

Comment: In the pc specifications it says that it does indeed have PS/2 synaptic touchpad but it is strange that it has stopped working.

Comment: Check BIOS settings and Fn+Fx button.

Comment: @Pilot6 what is this command for?